# PHP - GD, ImageMagick etc.. font thickness?

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to convert a photoshop mockup to GD/ImageMagick for dynamically editing the text (for use in forum signatures etc). I'm having trouble with the font quality at small sizes. It is too thin and undefined and blurry if I don't use a bold version of the font. If I disable anti-aliasing, it is even more thin and is completely unreadable. The font looks great in the bold version, but it is too thick for the design. I'd like to have the font weight/thickness be half way between regular and bold. Is this possible? I cannot see a function for setting font weight in GD or ImageMagick. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at `-strokewidth` within Imagemagick. It will outline the font with the value of `-strokewidth` in whatever color you specify with `-stroke`.  Not the same as a `thicker` font exactly, but may work for you.